# Solving a nonlinear equation system

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I have to solve a non-linear equation system which describes the kinematics of a five pieces mechanism.

```
ω1 = 3; r = 1.2; ϑc = 10 °; h = 0.05; e = 0.03; l3 = 0.1; l4 = 0.12;
l1 = 30.107; l2 = 160.027; l5 = 128.514;

(*fi vektor def*)

ϕ = {x1 - l1/2*Cos[ϑ1] + l5 == 0, 
y1 - l1/2*Sin[ϑ1] == 0, 
x1 + l1/2*Cos[ϑ1] - x2 + l2/2*Cos[ϑ2] == 0,
y1 + l1/2*Sin[ϑ1] - y2 + l2/2*Sin[ϑ2] == 
0, x2 + l2/2*Cos[ϑ2] - x3 + 
0.2*l3*Cos[ϑ3] == 0, 
y2 + l2/2*Sin[ϑ2] - y3 - 0.2*l3*Sin[ϑ3] == 
0, x3 + 0.8*l3*Cos[ϑ3] == 0, 
y3 - 0.8*l3*Sin[ϑ3] == 0, 
x3 - x4 + l4/2*Cos[ϑ4] == 0, 
y3 - y4 + l4/2*Sin[ϑ4] == 0, 
x5 - x4 - l4/2*Cos[ϑ4] == 0, 
y5 - y4 - l4/2*Sin[ϑ4] == 0, ϑ5 == 0, 
y5 - h == 0};
σ = {ϑ1 - ω1*t == 0};
F = Join[ϕ, σ];
q = {x1, y1, ϑ1, x2, y2, ϑ2, x3, y3, ϑ3, x4, y4, ϑ4, x5, y5, ϑ5};

$Assumptions = 
  {-2 π < ϑ1 < 2 π, -2 π < ϑ2 < 2 π, -2 π < ϑ3 < 2 π, 
   -2 π < ϑ4 < 2 π, -2 π < ϑ5 < 2 π};

NSolve[F, q, Reals]
```

`F` contains the equations. I want to solve the system for some time steps (t, the last equation{t,0,10}). I have to get the element of `q` vector in every time step.  How can I do this?

I tried with the attached code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `NSolve` does not look at `$Assumptions`,